# Number of Results Yotube API

Tags: python, youtube-api

This is the sample code from the Youtube API that allows you to get some search results on a video. I do not want to the videos but I want the number of search results. For example, I want to know how many GTA videos there are without knowing the name of each one. When you a type a search term in youtube it shows you the number of search results on the right-hand corner. I was wondering if anyone knew how you could do this programmatically.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

DEVELOPER_KEY = "#"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(keyword,Max):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=keyword,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=Max
  ).execute()

  videos = []

  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))

  print ("Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n")


try:
    youtube_search("GTA",10)
    #Try to figure out how you can get the number of results in a search
except HttpError as e:
    print ("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of results using :

```
search_response["pageInfo"]["totalResults"]
```

But according to [Search List properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#properties) for the field `pageInfo.totalResults` :

> The total number of results in the result set.Please note that the
>   value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In
>   addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.

As there is more than 1,000,000 videos in the result (for the term `GTA`) it will only return the value 1,000,000 in this case